# C# late binding and File exceptions

Tags: c#, async-await, filenotfoundexception, late-binding

Simple host app searching for assemblies by special Interface and importing from them list of delegates, now it's `Func<string,string>`. 
Then it can execute any `Func<T,T>` and there's no problem. 
Problems starts when any of this `Func` tries to access file, which doesn't exist.

No try-catch block, no `File.Exists` doesn't helps — when function tries to access a file (anyway, read, get stream, check, etc) — whole app just fails with `FileNotFound` in `mscorlib`.

How this can be fixed? App is really critical, and I can't perform file check in app, only just in assemblies.

UPD: Yes, that delegates contains `async` logic.

UPD2: Parts of code:

```
    try
    {
        if(!File.Exists(filePath)) return null;

                using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(destinationFilePath))
                {
                    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(filePath))
                    {
                    //some logic there
                    }
                 }
     }
    catch 
    {

    }
```

Exception thrown at File.Exists().

This code used to import assemblies.

```
Commands = new Dictionary<string, Func<string, string>>(); 
foreach (string f in fileNames)
                {

                    Assembly asm = Assembly.LoadFrom(f);
                    var types = asm.GetTypes();
                    foreach(Type t in types)
                    {

                        if (t.GetInterface("IMountPoint") != null)
                        {

                            var obj = Activator.CreateInstance(t);
                            var cmds = ((IMountPoint)obj).Init(EntryPoint);
                            foreach (var cmd in cmds)
                            {
                                if (!Commands.ContainsKey(cmd.Key.Trim().ToUpper()))
                                {
                                    Commands.Add(cmd.Key.Trim().ToUpper(), cmd.Value);
                                }

                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
```

And this code to run delegates:

```
string input = Console.ReadLine();
string res = Commands[command_key](input);
```

Comment: Can you provide some code please?

Comment: Are those assemblies loaded in the same appdomain?

Comment: What type of code you want? Solution is a big and I'm think I wrote all that needed upper.

Comment: Yes, AppDomain same.

Comment: Show example code where you are experiencing the error. The problem is with implementation, and you're not showing that. Why do you not use Try/Catch blocks to handle scenarios like this?

Comment: You should show how you're loading the assemblies (i.e. post that code). Post a sample method that fails (i.e. show the file access) and share the exact, complete exception message that you're getting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's shameful. 
I'm using late binding and forgot to copy assemblies manually, so assemblies with file existence checking are not loaded by app and it used old ones. 
Sorry, guys.